# Converting String to datePicker Format

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

In my project, I have a page that contains a `datepicker` element. I also have a date which is in the form of a `string`. I want to display the string `(date)` in the field of the `datePicker`. Is there any way to do this ?

This is my code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public void prevf()
{
    String dates="28/12/2002";
    LocalDate date=LocalDate.parse(dates);
    EndDateF.setValue(date); //Where EndDateF is a datePicker field
}
```

This had no effect, as the `datePicker` (`EndDateF`) was still blank.

I tried doing something like this as well:

```
Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
```

But this converts it to `Date`, and not `LocalDate`.

Is there any way to convert a `String` to such a format that can be displayed in the field of the `datepicker` ?

Comment: Hello, I fixed the imports and the error disappeared. But, is there any method to set the String in the datePicker's field ?

Comment: Well, I tried doing what they had suggested, but it didnt work. I edited my question to show you my complete code, because this setting of date is inside a `void` method. Can the date be set, only in a `static ` method ?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and don't forget to study the api doc of DatePicker carefully: its type is LocalDate, _not_ Date.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly unrelated to the code you posted. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D, Sorry if my example was unclear. I thought that I had included all the required details. Ill try to ensure that it is proper next time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you convert a `String` to `LocalDate` which is of a specific `pattern`:

```java
String dateAsString = "28/12/2002";

DateTimeFormatter customDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

And then set the value:

```java
endDateDatePicker.setValue(localDate);
```

Comment: please don't propagate violations of naming conventions ..

Comment: yes, I know - but you shouldn't, at least not without a comment on how to improve the names :)

Comment: Thanks @Renis1235 for the answer, it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
datepicker.setValue(datepicker.getConverter().fromString(String));
```

this converts to datepicker format, default is this

> yyyy-MM-dd